# Outlook rest api V2.0

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi

I created a web application that is using the outlook rest api V2.0.
I can authenticate the user en get the mail massages en calendar items. Problem is when i want to send a mail i am getting http error 400.

My outlook.php file

```html
<?php



 class OutlookService 
 {
    private static $outlookApiUrl = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0";
      
 public static function stuurEmail($access_token, $user_email, $data) 
   {
   
   
   $getMessagesUrl = self::$outlookApiUrl."/Me/sendmail?".http_build_query($data);

   return self::makeApiCall($access_token, $user_email, "POST", $getMessagesUrl);
   
   } 
  
  
  
  
  public static function sendMail ($access_token,$user_email)
   {
    $sentMessagesParameters = '{"Message":{"Subject":"Meet for lunch?","Body":{"ContentType":"Text","Content":"The new cafeteria is open."},"ToRecipients":[{"EmailAddress":{"Address":"danny.herremans@rkg.vlaanderen"}}]},"SaveToSentItems":"true"}';
   
   
   

   $json=json_encode($sentMessagesParameters, true);

    $getMessagesUrl = self::$outlookApiUrl."/me/sendmail?".http_build_query($sentMessagesParameters);


   return self::makeApiCall($access_token, $user_email, "POST",$getMessageUrl,$json);

   } 
  
  
  public static function getPhoto($access_token) 
   {
     $getUserParameters = array (
    // Only return the user's display name and email address
    "\$select" => "Photo"
     );

     $getUserUrl = self::$outlookApiUrl."/Me?".http_build_query($getUserParameters);

     return self::makeApiCall($access_token, "", "GET", $getUserUrl);
   
   
   
   }
  
  public static function getUser($access_token) 
   {
     $getUserParameters = array 
    (
    // Only return the user's display name and email address
    "\$select" => "DisplayName,EmailAddress,Alias"
     );

     $getUserUrl = self::$outlookApiUrl."/Me?".http_build_query($getUserParameters);

     return self::makeApiCall($access_token, "", "GET", $getUserUrl);
   }

    public static function getMessages($access_token, $user_email) 
   {
     $getMessagesParameters = array (
    // Only return Subject, ReceivedDateTime, and From fields
    "\$select" => "Subject,ReceivedDateTime,From",
    // Sort by ReceivedDateTime, newest first
    "\$orderby" => "ReceivedDateTime DESC",
    // Return at most 10 results
    "\$top" => "10"
     );

     $getMessagesUrl = self::$outlookApiUrl."/Me/MailFolders/Inbox/Messages?".http_build_query($getMessagesParameters);

     return self::makeApiCall($access_token, $user_email, "GET", $getMessagesUrl);
   }
    
    public static function getEvents($access_token, $user_email) 
   {
     $getEventsParameters = array (
    // Only return Subject, Start, and End fields
    "\$select" => "Subject,Start,End",
    // Sort by Start, oldest first
    "\$orderby" => "Start/DateTime",
    // Return at most 10 results
    "\$top" => "10"
     );

     $getEventsUrl = self::$outlookApiUrl."/Me/Events?".http_build_query($getEventsParameters);

     return self::makeApiCall($access_token, $user_email, "GET", $getEventsUrl);
   }
    
    public static function getContacts($access_token, $user_email) 
   {
     $getContactsParameters = array (
    // Only return GivenName, Surname, and EmailAddresses fields
    "\$select" => "GivenName,Surname,EmailAddresses",
    // Sort by GivenName, A-Z
    "\$orderby" => "GivenName",
    // Return at most 10 results
    "\$top" => "10"
     );

     $getContactsUrl = self::$outlookApiUrl."/Me/Contacts?".http_build_query($getContactsParameters);

     return self::makeApiCall($access_token, $user_email, "GET", $getContactsUrl);
   }
    
    public static function makeApiCall($access_token, $user_email, $method, $url, $payload = NULL) 
   {
     // Generate the list of headers to always send.
     $headers = array(
    "User-Agent: php-tutorial/1.0",         // Sending a User-Agent header is a best practice.
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token, // Always need our auth token!
    "Accept: application/json",             // Always accept JSON response.
    "client-request-id: ".self::makeGuid(), // Stamp each new request with a new GUID.
    "return-client-request-id: true",       // Tell the server to include our request-id GUID in the response.
    "X-AnchorMailbox: ".$user_email         // Provider user's email to optimize routing of API call
     );

     $curl = curl_init($url);

     switch(strtoupper($method)) {
    case "GET":
      // Nothing to do, GET is the default and needs no
      // extra headers.
      error_log("Doing GET");
      break;
    case "POST":
      error_log("Doing POST");
      // Add a Content-Type header (IMPORTANT!)
      $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
      break;
    case "PATCH":
      error_log("Doing PATCH");
      // Add a Content-Type header (IMPORTANT!)
      $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
      break;
    case "DELETE":
      error_log("Doing DELETE");
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
      break;
    default:
      error_log("INVALID METHOD: ".$method);
      exit;
     }

     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
     $response = curl_exec($curl);
     error_log("curl_exec done.");

     $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
     error_log("Request returned status ".$httpCode);

     if ($httpCode >= 400) {
    return array('errorNumber' => $httpCode,
        'error' => 'Request returned HTTP error '.$httpCode);
     }

     $curl_errno = curl_errno($curl);
     $curl_err = curl_error($curl);

     if ($curl_errno) {
    $msg = $curl_errno.": ".$curl_err;
    error_log("CURL returned an error: ".$msg);
    curl_close($curl);
    return array('errorNumber' => $curl_errno,
        'error' => $msg);
     }
     else {
    error_log("Response: ".$response);
    curl_close($curl);
    return json_decode($response, true);
     }
   }
    
    // This function generates a random GUID.
    public static function makeGuid()
   {
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')) {
      error_log("Using 'com_create_guid'.");
      return strtolower(trim(com_create_guid(), '{}'));
    }
    else {
      error_log("Using custom GUID code.");
      $charid = strtolower(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
      $hyphen = chr(45);
      $uuid = substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
       .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
       .substr($charid, 12, 4).$hyphen
       .substr($charid, 16, 4).$hyphen
       .substr($charid, 20, 12);

      return $uuid;
    }
   }
  }
?>
```

So in my home.php file i have the following code for sending the mail

```html
if(isset($_POST['mailing']))
{    
    @extract($_POST);

      $arr = '{
      "Message": {
      "Subject": "Meet for lunch?",
      "Body": {
        "ContentType": "Text",
        "Content": "The new cafeteria is open."
      },
      "ToRecipients": [
        {
        "EmailAddress": {
          "Address": "xxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx"
        }
        }
      ]
      },
      "SaveToSentItems": "true"
    }';
    $data=json_encode($arr, true);

    $message = OutlookService::stuurEmail(oAuthService::getAccessToken($redirectUri), $_SESSION['user_email'], $data);

    print_r($message);



    echo"
      <div class='alert alert-success'>
      <a href='#' title='Sluit deze melding'
      class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;
      </a>

      <br>".$_SESSION['access_token']."<br>".$_SESSION['user_email']."<br>$data<br>


      </div>

      ";

}
```

When i wont to sent a mail i am getting the following error:

Warning: http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object. Incorrect value given in /var/www/vhosts/rkgvlaande05001/test/outlook.php on line 14 Array ( [errorNumber] => 400 [error] => Request returned HTTP error 400 )

Any idea what not right in the code or has anyone has a working example for the outlook rest api V2.0?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I checked you code and the sentMessagesParameters content is correct. However, I found this post mentioned, "you need to 'send mail as a user' permission for O365 Exchange Online in Azure AD if you want to send a mail message with REST API ". Please see the following link:

[Outlook Rest Api sending Mail Request returned status 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37546885/outlook-rest-api-sending-mail-request-returned-status-400)

Comment: Hi Simon, Thx for your reply. I have foud the https 400 error. There was a problem with the http_build_query($data). It whas not passing the JSON string.

Comment: Great. Maybe you can mark your reply as answer and close the post.